# How to use Layout file from library project in android

Tags: android, android-library

I have two android projects 1. Main Project 2. Library project. I am referring the Library project in my Main project. I have a fragment in Main Project which should use the layout(.xml) file in library project. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you want to use it inside your code you can refer to it like this:

```
com.library_package.R.layout.library_layout
```

so for example you can inflate layout with:

```
LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(com.library_package.R.layout.library_layout, this, true);
```

Comment: Hello @Bartosz Lipinski
what if i want to include it in a layout ?

Comment: I don't think you can (or at least I'm not aware of the way you could possibly do it)... You can create a new custom `View` class, that would inside inflate the layout with the inflater (like in my answer), though. Then create an instance of this custom `View` inside your layout.

Comment: For xml reference I saw an example uses this syntax: `implementation(project(path: ':libs:library_layout:app')) { exclude group: '...' }` I think the exclude clause is optional, you can then make a reference in your XML layout as an internal layout.